# Uninitialized constant User::TaxCloud

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Im integrating tax cloud with my application to calculate sales tax. When i tried to run tax cloud from console, its running good. See below

```
irb(main):002:0> u = User.last
irb(main):006:0> u.calculate_sales_tax
7.0
```

The method in user model.

```
def calculate_sales_tax
  origin = TaxCloud::Address.new(
      :city => 'xxxx',
      :state => 'NJ',
      :zip5 => '08106')
  destination = TaxCloud::Address.new(
      :city => 'xxxxx',
      :state => "#{self.state}",
      :zip5 => "#{self.zip_code}")
  transaction = TaxCloud::Transaction.new(
      :customer_id => "#{self.id}",
      :origin => origin,
      :destination => destination)
  transaction.cart_items << TaxCloud::CartItem.new(
      :index => 0,
      :item_id => 'xxxx',
      :tic => TaxCloud::TaxCodes::PREWRITTEN_COMPUTER_SOFTWARE_DELIVERED_ELECTRONICALLY,
      :price => 100.00,
      :quantity => 1)
  lookup = transaction.lookup   # this will return a TaxCloud::Responses::Lookup instance
  puts lookup.tax_amount        # total tax amount
end
```

Its working fine when I call from the rails console but when the call is from controller, i'm getting:

```
 NameError (uninitialized constant User::TaxCloud)
```

Controller:

```
class SubscriptionsController < ApplicationController
  load_and_authorize_resource :user
  load_and_authorize_resource :through => :user

  def index
    @sales_tax = @user.calculate_sales_tax
  end
end
```

Can you guys please help me... Thanks in advance

Comment: Please post your controller where User::TaxCloud is accessed.

Comment: Is TaxCloud defined in `lib`?

Comment: the `/lib` folder - something like: `/lib/tax_cloud/address`

Comment: no. its not defined in lib

Comment: Can you add the paths to all the files containing the `TaxCloud` classes.

Comment: Dont mind... Im new to this... Can you temme where i can find that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90558/discussion-between-gavin-miller-and-sheharose).

Comment: Have you tried a require in the controller?

Answer (score 0):

You can use it "::TaxCloud::Address" place on "TaxCloud::Address"